# VS Community 2015 Missing Solution Github

Tags: git, github, missing-data, tortoisegit, vs-community-edition

I truly hope you can help me. I am a new user and I had all my homework assignments in one solution in VS. I installed git and tortoisegit and created a github account in order to save my files there and access them from another device.
Unfortunately somehow my .sln files are missing from the user/mydocs/vs/projects/ folder. I only have obj and bin folders with .exes and other files but not .cs . I think I lost all my work:(
Thanks in advance for all your time and attention!

Comment: Could you give us more details? What have you done step by step?

Comment: If that's your repository, https://github.com/Pessinger/CSharpFundamendalsHomew0rk  then you just need to clone it. However there are no code there, just a new solution.

Comment: Yes this is my github. I think I cloned it. And when I was committing the solution something happened. When I was about to publish an error message advised I cannot and now the .cs files are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Would be nice to the the error message.